# Show half of the other item on Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel, owl-carousel

Im trying to display part of the other item on the left side and display full item on the right side using owl carousel.

Per each item I have a banner image and the text, which are split using the bootstrap grid columns.

I was able to achieve the partial display using stagepadding: 200
and to display the partial image only on the left side I used right:-200px in css on .owl-stage class.

Now, the problem is that on the left side I need to display the banner image of that partial slide, not the text...

owl slider has the active class, so with css I tried to hide that text column when it is NOT active... it worked, but all I see is empty space on the left side, it did not push the banner image automatically.

Please view the screenshots
What Im trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJXGQ.jpg
What I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YquFy.jpg

that white space is filled with text column actually, but is hidden with css. I need the banner image from the left to take over that whole space when its partially displayed, but when that specific slide item is active, then I will show both image and text as usual.

This is my js script.

```js
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
     center: true, 
     autoplay:false, 
     autoplayTimeout:5000,
     autoplayHoverPause:false,
     stagePadding: 150, 
     items:1,           
     loop:true,     
     margin:0,      
     responsive:{
      600:{
       items:1 
      }
     },
     onInitialized : function(){
      if($('.owl-item').first().hasClass('active'))
       $('.owl-prev').hide();
      else
       $('.owl-prev').show();
     } 
    }); 
   });
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to do this is by using `stagePadding: 100`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      margin: 10,
      loop: true,
      items: 1,
      stagePadding: 100
   });
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth this is the best answer. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

You may need have a try with these options:

1.`autoWidth: true,` // Set fixed width for your items;
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html

2.`rtl:true,`        // Keep your item stand to the right;
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/rtl.html

Answer (score 2):

it's very easy "also Works on **angular 2+** (ngx-owl-carousel-o)"

just add margin and change number of items from 1 to 1.5  or 1.4 or what you want.

**example:-**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                center: true, 
                autoplay:false, 
                autoplayTimeout:5000,
                autoplayHoverPause:false,
                items:1.4,           
                loop:true,     
                margin:20,      
                responsive:{
                    600:{
                        items:1.4 
                    }
                },
                onInitialized : function(){
                    if($('.owl-item').first().hasClass('active'))
                        $('.owl-prev').hide();
                    else
                        $('.owl-prev').show();
                } 
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only the half of the next item in carousel you need to add styles for .owl-wrapper (make sure it has box-sizing: content-box)

```
.owl-wrapper {
   padding-right: 60px;
}
```

And wrap your carousel with helper div, so you can make your container 100% width back:

```
.owl-carousel-helper {
   margin-right: 60px;
}
```

So html will look like this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel-helper">
   <div class="owl-carousel">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting the `items: 1.5` or any other float value (**BUT IT MAKES DARGING HARD**)

The Best Way is To Simply Add More Margin

```
    SlideOptions = {
        dots: false,
        loop: false,
        nav: false,
        items: 2,
        margin: 160,
        rtl: true,
        responsive: false
    };
```

in my case the width of each element was 250px

so i set a margin of 150

*note: you can try setting responsive false or true to manage width yourself*

here is the picture of the result: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7bRX.jpg